# Inserting large data set using procedure in Oracle Database

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I have a table AA contains 6 columns (`a`,`b`,`c`,`d`,`e`,`f`), with 200 million records having `a`,`b`,`c` as composite key. Column `a`, or column `b`, or column `c` may have multiple duplicate entries. column `c` has multiple entries with each `a` and `b`.

I have to copy the values of the columns `a`,`b`,`d`,`e`,`f` (`c` is not present) into another table AB having columns `a`,`b`,`d`,`e`,`f`  with `a`,`b`,`d` as composite key so that column `d` can have a maximum value's of 2 and `a`,`b`,`d` should have maximum entries of 2.

I have written a procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Table_CHANGES(d IN AB.d%TYPE)
AS
  aaa     AB.a%TYPE;
  aab AB.b%TYPE;
  i             NUMBER   :=   0;
  countRow      NUMBER; 

CURSOR distinctUserIdCursor IS 
    SELECT DISTINCT urt.a, urt.b FROM AA urt WHERE urt.d = aad ORDER BY  urt.a;

BEGIN
    OPEN distinctUserIdCursor;
    LOOP

    FETCH distinctUserIdCursor INTO aaa, aab;
    EXIT WHEN distinctUserIdCursor%NOTFOUND;

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO countRow FROM AB ur
    WHERE ur.a = aaa 
    AND ur.b = aab
    AND ur.d = aad;

    IF (countRow > 0) THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Entry exist in AB');
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO AB 
        SELECT urt.a, urt.b, urt.d, urt.e, 
        urt.f FROM AA urt 
        WHERE urt.a = aaa 
        AND urt.d = aad
        AND urt.b = aab
        AND ROWNUM = 1;

        i := i+1;
    END IF;

    IF (i = 1000) THEN
        COMMIT;
        i := 0;
    END IF;

END LOOP;
COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('Error in Insertion of new role' 
                || '~~~~' || SQLERRM);
CLOSE distinctUserIdCursor;
END;
/
```

While executing this procedure in Toad as `exec Table_CHANGES('value1')` and `exec Table_CHANGES('value2')`, It takes around 40 mins and keeps executing in toad. It is hard to know If toad is actually performing the task or gets sleep.

Can I optimise this procedure so that It should take less time for inserting tens of millions of data in table AB?

Answer (score 0):

I tired to achieve what you are doing using collections. Please see if thats fits your requirement and improves performance.

```
create table AA(a number, b number,c number,d number, e number,f number );

create table AB(a number, b number,d number, e number,f number );
```

Procedure:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE procedure Table_CHANGES(aad IN AB.d%TYPE)
    AS
    --  aaa           AB.a%TYPE;
    --  aab           AB.b%TYPE;
    --  i             NUMBER   :=   0;
    --  countRow      NUMBER; 

   ///**Put some filtering logic here like i have put a minus ***///
    CURSOR distinctUserIdCursor(aad number) IS 
        SELECT DISTINCT  urt.a, 
                urt.b,
                urt.d, 
                urt.e, 
                urt.f 
        FROM AA urt      
        WHERE urt.d = aad

        minus
        SELECT DISTINCT ur.a, 
                ur.b,
                ur.d, 
                ur.e, 
                ur.f 
        FROM AB ur      
        WHERE ur.d = aad;


    type var_cur is table of distinctUserIdCursor%rowtype;

    var var_cur;

    BEGIN
        OPEN distinctUserIdCursor(aad);

        LOOP

        FETCH distinctUserIdCursor bulk collect into var limit 100;       
         EXIT WHEN distinctUserIdCursor%NOTFOUND;

         FORALL i IN 1 .. var.count SAVE EXCEPTIONS
          INSERT INTO AB 
          VALUES var(i);              

        END LOOP;

        CLOSE distinctUserIdCursor;

    COMMIT;

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            dbms_output.put_line('Error in Insertion of new role' || '~~~~' || SQLERRM);
          FOR indx IN 1 .. SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.COUNT
             LOOP
                DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS (indx).ERROR_INDEX|| ': '
                   || SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS (indx).ERROR_CODE);
          END LOOP;

    END;
    /
```

Execution:

```
execute Table_CHANGES(3)
```